# CasperJS Loading resource failed with status=fail (HTTP 200)

Tags: web-scraping, casperjs

After setting "Any Date", output format, and clicking a link on a bank site, some javascript runs in the background, download.qfx is called with a GET request, and then a CSV file is downloaded.

Unfortunately, when I try to replicate these actions with CasperJS the call to download.qfx fails and I get an incomplete CSV file (It has worked once or twice, but I can't figure out why). I've looked at all of the stack overflow questions referencing this error and found no solution.

I call the following piece of a script with:

```
casperjs --ssl-protocol=any --ignore-ssl-errors=true casper.js
```

Here is the partial script:

```
// Call download functions for transaction data
casper.then(function(){
    //this.click(x("//a[contains(text(), 'Download')]")); // 'clicking' the link or calling the subsequent javascript both show the same result
    this.evaluate(function(){
        urchinTracker('/download_transactions/continue');
        submitForm('download');
        return false;
    });
});

// Download transaction data
casper.then(function(){
    casper.waitForResource("download.qfx", function(resource) {
        this.download(resource.url, 'temp/' + userid + '.csv');
    });
});

casper.run();
```

I've attached the debug log, because it's strange that the page seems to 'navigate' to pages after clicking the link, because in the browser doesn't do that when you click the link, but maybe I'm misunderstanding something.
[image]

I'm using casperjs 1.0.0 and phantomjs 1.9.8

Comment: Try using CasperJS 1.1-beta3. 1.0.0 is nearly three years old.

Comment: Did the update. Still same error, but now is 302, instead of 200

Comment: There's a get request and a post request before the download.qfx runs in the browser. Can that be what's causing the problems?